# Show that $f$ does not belong to $L^{p + \epsilon}$ for every $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\Omega = \left(0, \frac{1}{2}\right), f(x)=(x\log^2x)^{-1/p}$, show that $f \notin L^{p+\varepsilon}\left(\Omega\right)$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

I tried to do it by definition, i.e. prove that integral $\left(\int_\Omega f^{(-p-\varepsilon)/p}\right)^{1/(p+\varepsilon)}))$ is unbounded,

but haven't come up with any suitable inequalities. Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$\int_{t}^{0.5} x^{a-1} (-\log(x))^b d x
=\left[\frac{x^a (-\log(x))^b}{a}\right]_t^{0.5}
+\frac{b}{a}\int_{t}^{0.5} x^{a-1} (-\log(x))^{b-1} d x$$

What can you say if $x^{a-1} (-\log(x))^b \in L^1([0;0.5])$ ?

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain, why do you have minus sign in front of $\log$?

Comment: Because $\log(x) < 0$ in $\Omega$. Knowing only that $b\in {\mathbb R}$, $c^b$ is not defined when $c < 0$. You can use $|\log(x)|^b$ if you want.